# SHA2 vs SHA3 popularity

Tags: sha-3, sha-2

Does anybody know or can point me to a source about SHA2 vs SHA3 usage statistics.
SHA3 is newer and is claimed to be more secure but ... is it more widely used in real life deployments?

Comment: Compared to SHA-2? No, SHA-3 is definitely not more used. I'd hazard a guess that even SHA-1 surpasses the use of SHA-3. Define "more secure". One of the outcomes of the SHA-3 hashing competition was that SHA-2 withstand attacks surprisingly well (even though it uses the same basic construction as SHA-1, but with rounds of a higher complexity).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'd primarily define 'more secure' as SHA-3 doesn't suffer length extension attacks. It's also the result of a competition, and Keccak has had [lots](https://keccak.team/third_party.html) of third-party cryptanalysis considering its more limited use.

Comment: @samuel-lucas6 Length extension attacks are not that important. They are only useful when the hash algorithm is used together with a secret, and in that case we generally just use the HMAC construction. So the issue is mainly one for cryptographers and protocol designers (and probably crypto-newbe's that assume that they are one of those, of course).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes True, I'm really just referring to [this](https://www.cryptologie.net/article/400/maybe-dont-skip-sha-3/) argument. From a misuse perspective, it makes more sense to use SHA-3. Personally though, I'd advocate for BLAKE2 or SHAKE. I don't think it makes sense to still use SHA-2 unless it's the only thing available/a requirement.

Comment: @samuel-lucas6 Hardware acceleration is a major reason to still use SHA-2. There isn't any for SHA-3 on common hardware (x64 and generic ARM processors), as far as I know anyway. And maybe the whole issue with using SHA-3 *or* SHAKE is an issue all by itself. By the way, ever lagging libraries such as the .NET framework don't yet support SHA-3 - of course if it was up to Microsoft you'd be waiting forever for it.

Comment: Hmm, interesting conversation. @MaartenBodewes, @ samuel-lucas6, thank you for your comments.
However, this just highlights the point: various arguments for and against. Statistics is a good indicator, albeit taken with a pinch of salt ...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Oops, I forgot about that. I expect the only thing that competes is accelerated BLAKE3, which is likely used less than SHA-3. Yes, as someone who codes in C#, the state of .NET crypto compared to Go/Rust is quite sad. @ user104734 Indeed. They're both fine, just don't trust the statistics for SHA-1.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes (Some) ARMv8 CPUs have hardware instructions to compute Keccak operations, including Apple's A-line and M-line (this doesn't affect the main point about hardware acceleration, it's mostly just a FYI)

Answer (score 1):

SHA-256  is used in bitcoin mining, and the number of calculations done with this function for mining by dedicated hardware, GPU, and software means for years is enormous. You can find a daily statistics of the usage in SHA-256 in many bitcoin sites. SHA-256 is secure and efficient. One of the motivations for the development of SHA-3 is the fact that in security proofs SHA-256 is assumed to represent a "random oracle", while it can be proved that SHA-2 is not a random oracle. The sponge function avoids this problem, and if the permutation is uses assumed to be pseudo random, the sponge can be shown to be a random function.

Comment: Interesting point @Evgeni-Vaknin.
Bitcoin does many transactions indeed, but I doubt it beats the rest of the IT/Internet/Electronics use cases in numbers ...
BTW, I wonder if the BTC community has tabled a proposal to move from SHA2 to SHA3 ?

Comment: As for bitcoin moving to SHA3, well, that would make the existing hardware miners worthless (as they are designed around SHA-2).  I would expect some amount of pushback...